# Вставить значение из БД в поле

Tags: php, html

Есть 2 поля на странице

```
div class="profile__label">Username</div>
                        <input class="profile__input" type="text"disabled>
                        <div class="profile__label">Email</div>
                        <input class="profile__input" type="text"disabled>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при переходе на страницу эти поля были заполнены данными из таблицы БД?

Comment: Написать скрипт на php для подключения к бд, и вытягивания данных (в инете много материала, думаю с поиском проблем не возникнет) после возвратить массив данных из php в Ваш скрипт, и вывести его на js.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov он указал...php

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц ой, подслеп я на ночь глядя ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Midnight вы решили задачу?